# Why does image-type from image-mode not use imagemagick?

Tags: emacs, imagemagick, elisp

Imagemagick makes transform operations possible for images. But, for jpeg-images image-mode uses the image format jpg and not imagemagick. Why is that so? Is there some deeper reason behind that?

If one overwrites that behaviour with the following advice scaling and rotation of jpeg images with `image-transform-set-scale` and `image-transform-set-rotation` in image-mode becomes possible.

Emacs-Version: 24.3.93.1

```lisp
(defadvice image-type (after imagemagick activate)
  "Use imagemagick if it can handle that imagetype."
  (when (assoc-string ad-return-value (imagemagick-types) t)
    (setq ad-return-value 'imagemagick)))
```

Comment: Which Emacs version do you use? I'm running 24.3.1 and there is no `imagemagick-types` function. Do you mean `imagemagick-filter-types`?

Comment: @rudolfo.christ Emacs-Version is added to the question. Note, that you need an emacs compiled with the imagemagick-library.